# How to send a knockout model data or create a data to send as x-www-form-urlencoded using $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, knockout.js, playframework

I am using knockout JS and I am using a back end rest service which accepts only x-www-form-urlencoded (this cannot be modified). How can I send the KO model or create a request object to send to the back end service via $.ajax post?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you looked at the jQuery documentation for the `$.ajax` call to see if it supports sending `x-www-form-urlencoded` data?

Comment: @PatrickSteele I tried that part. My challenge it I have a knockout object and I am not sure how to transform that into a map like {key = [{object json}]}

Comment: When you say you have a "knockout object" are you talking about a single knockout observable?  Or are you talking about your entire view model?

Comment: I am talking about a view model

Answer (score 0):

Use Knockout's [built-in functionality to convert your view model to a regular JSON object](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) (no observables -- just the data).  Then use a [jQuery $.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to send the data.